# Is that possible to calculate power function of two BigNumbers in Javacard?

Tags: javacard, bignum

Consider I have two numbers `a` and `b`. Is that possible to calculate `a^b` inside a javacard?

Few month ago I saw a master thesis (that I could not find it again!) who had used crypto resources like RSA engine in javacard to calculate BigNumber multiplication. Does anyone know a similar or other solution to handle this problem?

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32160781/5128464).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @vlp answer, I could find an example applet inside [JCMathLib github](https://github.com/OpenCryptoProject/JCMathLib) that I could use for big number calculations. This is the sample applet I used:

```
package JCMathLibTest ;

import javacard.framework.APDU;
import javacard.framework.Applet;
import javacard.framework.CardRuntimeException;
import javacard.framework.ISO7816;
import javacard.framework.ISOException;
import javacard.framework.JCSystem;
import javacard.framework.PINException;
import javacard.framework.SystemException;
import javacard.framework.TransactionException;
import javacard.framework.Util;
import javacard.security.CryptoException;

public class JCMathLibTest extends Applet {
    // Main instruction CLAss
    public final static byte CLA_OC_UT                  = (byte) 0xB0; // OpenCrypto Unit Tests

    // INStructions
    public final static byte INS_BN_ADD                 = (byte) 0x21;
    public final static byte INS_BN_SUB                 = (byte) 0x22;
    public final static byte INS_BN_MUL                 = (byte) 0x23;
    public final static byte INS_BN_EXP                 = (byte) 0x24;
    public final static byte INS_BN_MOD                 = (byte) 0x25;
    
    public final static byte INS_BN_ADD_MOD             = (byte) 0x30;
    public final static byte INS_BN_SUB_MOD             = (byte) 0x31;
    public final static byte INS_BN_MUL_MOD             = (byte) 0x32;
    public final static byte INS_BN_EXP_MOD             = (byte) 0x33;
    public final static byte INS_BN_POW2_MOD            = (byte) 0x35;

    public final static byte INS_PERF_SETSTOP = (byte) 0xf5;
    
    
    static boolean bIsSimulator = false; 
    static boolean bTEST_256b_CURVE = true;
    static boolean bTEST_512b_CURVE = false;
    
    short[]         m_memoryInfo = null;
    short           m_memoryInfoOffset = 0;
    
    ECConfig        m_ecc = null;
    
    ECCurve         m_testCurve = null;

    ECPoint         m_testPoint1 = null;
    ECPoint         m_testPoint2 = null;
    
    byte[]          m_customG = null;
    ECCurve         m_testCurveCustom = null;
    ECPoint         m_testPointCustom = null;
    
    Bignat          m_testBN1;
    Bignat          m_testBN2;
    Bignat          m_testBN3;

    public JCMathLibTest() {
        OperationSupport.getInstance().setCard(OperationSupport.SIMULATOR); // TODO set your card

        m_memoryInfo = new short[(short) (7 * 3)]; // Contains RAM and EEPROM memory required for basic library objects
        if (bTEST_256b_CURVE) {
            m_ecc = new ECConfig((short) 256);
        }
        if (bTEST_512b_CURVE) {
            m_ecc = new ECConfig((short) 512);
        }
        

        // Pre-allocate test objects (no new allocation for every tested operation)
        if (bTEST_256b_CURVE) {
            m_testCurve = new ECCurve(false, SecP256r1.p, SecP256r1.a, SecP256r1.b, SecP256r1.G, SecP256r1.r);
            //m_memoryInfoOffset = snapshotAvailableMemory((short) 3, m_memoryInfo, m_memoryInfoOffset);
            // m_testCurveCustom and m_testPointCustom will have G occasionally changed so we need separate ECCurve
            m_customG = new byte[(short) SecP256r1.G.length];
            Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(SecP256r1.G, (short) 0, m_customG, (short) 0, (short) SecP256r1.G.length);
            m_testCurveCustom = new ECCurve(false, SecP256r1.p, SecP256r1.a, SecP256r1.b, m_customG, SecP256r1.r);
        }
        if (bTEST_512b_CURVE) {
            m_testCurve = new ECCurve(false, P512r1.p, P512r1.a, P512r1.b, P512r1.G, P512r1.r);
            // m_testCurveCustom and m_testPointCustom will have G occasionally changed so we need separate ECCurve
            m_customG = new byte[(short) P512r1.G.length];
            Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(P512r1.G, (short) 0, m_customG, (short) 0, (short) P512r1.G.length);
            m_testCurveCustom = new ECCurve(false, P512r1.p, P512r1.a, P512r1.b, m_customG, P512r1.r);
        }

        // Testing Bignat objects used in tests
        byte memoryType = JCSystem.MEMORY_TYPE_TRANSIENT_RESET;
        m_testBN1 = new Bignat(m_ecc.MAX_BIGNAT_SIZE, memoryType, m_ecc.bnh);
        m_testBN2 = new Bignat(m_ecc.MAX_BIGNAT_SIZE, memoryType, m_ecc.bnh);
        m_testBN3 = new Bignat(m_ecc.MAX_BIGNAT_SIZE, memoryType, m_ecc.bnh);
        
        short intLen = 4;
        m_testINT1 = new Integer(intLen, m_ecc.bnh);
        m_testINT2 = new Integer(intLen, m_ecc.bnh);
    }
    
    public static void install(byte[] bArray, short bOffset, byte bLength) {
        // GP-compliant JavaCard applet registration
        if (bLength == 0) {
            bIsSimulator = true;
        }
        new JCMathLibTest().register();
    }

    public boolean select() {
        //updateAfterReset();
        return true;
    }
    public void process(APDU apdu) {
        byte[] apdubuf = apdu.getBuffer();

        // Good practice: Return 9000 on SELECT
        if (selectingApplet()) {
            return;
        }

        // Check CLA byte
        if (apdubuf[ISO7816.OFFSET_CLA] != CLA_OC_UT) {
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_CLA_NOT_SUPPORTED);
        }

        // Process Input
        short dataLen = apdu.setIncomingAndReceive(); // returns length of data field

        try {
            switch (apdubuf[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS]) {
                
                case INS_BN_STR:
                    test_BN_STR(apdu, dataLen);
                    break;
                    
                case INS_BN_ADD:
                    test_BN_ADD(apdu, dataLen);
                    break;
                    
                case INS_BN_SUB:
                    test_BN_SUB(apdu, dataLen);
                    break;
                    
                case INS_BN_MUL:
                    test_BN_MUL(apdu, dataLen, true);
                    break;
                
                case INS_BN_EXP:
                    test_BN_EXP(apdu, dataLen);
                    break;
                
                case INS_BN_SQRT:
                    test_BN_SQRT(apdu, dataLen);
                    break;
                    
                case INS_BN_MOD:
                    test_BN_MOD(apdu, dataLen);
                    break;
                    
                case INS_BN_ADD_MOD:
                    test_BN_ADD_MOD(apdu, dataLen);
                    break;
                    
                case INS_BN_SUB_MOD:
                    test_BN_SUB_MOD(apdu, dataLen);
                    break;
                    
                case INS_BN_MUL_MOD:
                    test_BN_MUL_MOD(apdu, dataLen);
                    break;
                    
                case INS_BN_EXP_MOD:
                    test_BN_EXP_MOD(apdu, dataLen);
                    break;
                    
                case INS_BN_POW2_MOD:
                    test_BN_POW2_MOD(apdu, dataLen);
                    break;

                default:
                    // good practice: If you don't know the INStruction, say so:
                    ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_INS_NOT_SUPPORTED);
            }
            // Capture all reasonable exceptions and change into readable ones (instead of 0x6f00) 
        } catch (ISOException e) {
            throw e; // Our exception from code, just re-emit
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            ISOException.throwIt(ReturnCodes.SW_ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException);
        } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
            ISOException.throwIt(ReturnCodes.SW_ArithmeticException);
        } catch (ArrayStoreException e) {
            ISOException.throwIt(ReturnCodes.SW_ArrayStoreException);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            ISOException.throwIt(ReturnCodes.SW_NullPointerException);
        } catch (NegativeArraySizeException e) {
            ISOException.throwIt(ReturnCodes.SW_NegativeArraySizeException);
        } catch (CryptoException e) {
            ISOException.throwIt((short) (ReturnCodes.SW_CryptoException_prefix | e.getReason()));
        } catch (SystemException e) {
            ISOException.throwIt((short) (ReturnCodes.SW_SystemException_prefix | e.getReason()));
        } catch (PINException e) {
            ISOException.throwIt((short) (ReturnCodes.SW_PINException_prefix | e.getReason()));
        } catch (TransactionException e) {
            ISOException.throwIt((short) (ReturnCodes.SW_TransactionException_prefix | e.getReason()));
        } catch (CardRuntimeException e) {
            ISOException.throwIt((short) (ReturnCodes.SW_CardRuntimeException_prefix | e.getReason()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ISOException.throwIt(ReturnCodes.SW_Exception);
        }

    }

    void test_BN_ADD(APDU apdu, short dataLen) {
        byte[] apdubuf = apdu.getBuffer();
        short p1 = (short) (apdubuf[ISO7816.OFFSET_P1] & 0x00FF);

        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_ADD_1);
        Bignat num1 = m_testBN1;
        num1.set_size(p1);
        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_ADD_2);
        Bignat num2 = m_testBN2;
        num2.set_size((short) (dataLen - p1));
        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_ADD_3);
        Bignat sum = m_testBN3;
        sum.set_size((short) (p1 + 1));

        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_ADD_4);
        num1.from_byte_array(p1, (short)0, apdubuf, ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA);
        num2.from_byte_array((short) (dataLen - p1), (short)0, apdubuf, (short)(ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA+p1));
        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_ADD_5);
        sum.copy(num1);
        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_ADD_6);
        sum.add(num2);
        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_ADD_7);
        short len = sum.copy_to_buffer(apdubuf, (short) 0);
        apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short) 0, len);    
    }
                        
    void test_BN_SUB(APDU apdu, short dataLen) {
        byte[] apdubuf = apdu.getBuffer();
        short p1 = (short) (apdubuf[ISO7816.OFFSET_P1] & 0x00FF);

        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_SUB_1);
        Bignat sub1 = m_testBN1;
        sub1.set_size(p1);
        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_SUB_2);
        Bignat sub2 = m_testBN2;
        sub2.set_size((short) (dataLen - p1));
        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_SUB_3);
        Bignat result = m_testBN3;
        result.set_size((short) (p1 + 1));
        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_SUB_4);
        sub1.from_byte_array(dataLen, (short)0, apdubuf, ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA);
        sub2.from_byte_array(dataLen, (short)0, apdubuf, (short)(ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA+p1));
        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_SUB_5);
        result.copy(sub1);
        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_SUB_6);
        result.subtract(sub2);
        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_SUB_7);
        short len = result.copy_to_buffer(apdubuf, (short) 0);
        apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short) 0, len);
    }       
    
    void test_BN_MUL(APDU apdu, short dataLen, boolean bFastEngine) {
        byte[] apdubuf = apdu.getBuffer();
        short p1 = (short) (apdubuf[ISO7816.OFFSET_P1] & 0x00FF);

        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_MUL_1);    
        Bignat mul1 = m_testBN1;
        mul1.set_size(p1);
        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_MUL_2);
        Bignat mul2 = m_testBN2;
        mul2.set_size((short) (dataLen - p1));
        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_MUL_3);
        Bignat product = m_testBN3;
        product.set_size(dataLen);
        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_MUL_4);
        mul1.from_byte_array(p1, (short)0, apdubuf, ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA);
        mul2.from_byte_array((short)(dataLen-p1), (short)0, apdubuf, (short)(ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA+p1));
        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_MUL_5);
        if (bFastEngine && !bIsSimulator) {
            product.mult_rsa_trick(mul1, mul2, null, null);
        }
        else {
            product.mult_schoolbook(mul1, mul2);        
        }
        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_MUL_6);
        short len = product.copy_to_buffer(apdubuf, (short) 0);
        apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short) 0, len);
    }
    
    void test_BN_EXP(APDU apdu, short dataLen) {
        byte[] apdubuf = apdu.getBuffer();
        short p1 = (short) (apdubuf[ISO7816.OFFSET_P1] & 0x00FF);
        short p2 = (short) (apdubuf[ISO7816.OFFSET_P2] & 0x00FF);

        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_EXP_1);    
        Bignat base = m_testBN1;
        base.set_size(p1);
        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_EXP_2);
        Bignat exp = m_testBN2;
        exp.set_size((short) (dataLen - p1));
        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_EXP_3);
        Bignat res = m_testBN3;
        res.set_size((short) (m_ecc.MAX_BIGNAT_SIZE / 2));
        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_EXP_4);
        base.from_byte_array(p1, (short) 0, apdubuf, ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA);
        exp.from_byte_array((short) (dataLen - p1), (short) 0, apdubuf, (short)(ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA+p1));
        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_EXP_5);
        res.exponentiation(base, exp);
        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_EXP_6);
        short len = res.copy_to_buffer(apdubuf, (short) 0);
        apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short) 0, len);
    }
    
    
    void test_BN_MOD(APDU apdu, short dataLen) {
        byte[] apdubuf = apdu.getBuffer();
        short p1 = (short) (apdubuf[ISO7816.OFFSET_P1] & 0x00FF);

        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_MOD_1);
        Bignat num = m_testBN1;
        num.set_size(p1);
        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_MOD_2);
        Bignat mod = m_testBN2;
        mod.set_size((short) (dataLen - p1));
        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_MOD_3);
        num.from_byte_array(p1, (short)0, apdubuf, ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA);
        mod.from_byte_array((short)(dataLen-p1), (short)0, apdubuf, (short)(ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA+p1));
        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_MOD_4);
        num.mod(mod);
        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_MOD_5);
        short len = num.copy_to_buffer(apdubuf, (short) 0);
        apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short) 0, len);
    }
    
    void test_BN_ADD_MOD(APDU apdu, short dataLen) {
        byte[] apdubuf = apdu.getBuffer();
        short p1 = (short) (apdubuf[ISO7816.OFFSET_P1] & 0x00FF);
        short p2 = (short) (apdubuf[ISO7816.OFFSET_P2] & 0x00FF);

        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_ADD_MOD_1);
        Bignat num1 = m_testBN1;
        num1.set_size(p1);
        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_ADD_MOD_2);
        Bignat num2 = m_testBN2;
        num2.set_size(p2);
        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_ADD_MOD_3);
        Bignat mod = m_testBN3;
        mod.set_size((short) (dataLen - p1 - p2));
        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_ADD_MOD_4);
        num1.from_byte_array(p1, (short)0, apdubuf, ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA);
        num2.from_byte_array(p2, (short)0, apdubuf, (short)(ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA+p1));
        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_ADD_MOD_5);
        mod.from_byte_array((short)(dataLen-p1-p2), (short)0, apdubuf, (short)(ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA+p1+p2));
        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_ADD_MOD_6);
        num1.mod_add(num2, mod);
        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_ADD_MOD_7);
        short len = num1.copy_to_buffer(apdubuf, (short) 0);
        apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short) 0, len);
    }
        
    void test_BN_SUB_MOD(APDU apdu, short dataLen) {
        byte[] apdubuf = apdu.getBuffer();
        short p1 = (short) (apdubuf[ISO7816.OFFSET_P1] & 0x00FF);
        short p2 = (short) (apdubuf[ISO7816.OFFSET_P2] & 0x00FF);

        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_SUB_MOD_1);    
        Bignat num1 = m_testBN1;
        num1.set_size(p1);
        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_SUB_MOD_2);
        Bignat num2 = m_testBN2;
        num2.set_size(p2);
        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_SUB_MOD_3);
        Bignat mod = m_testBN3;
        mod.set_size((short) (dataLen - p1 - p2));
        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_SUB_MOD_4);
        num1.from_byte_array(p1, (short)0, apdubuf, ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA);
        num2.from_byte_array(p2, (short)0, apdubuf, (short)(ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA+p1));
        mod.from_byte_array((short)(dataLen-p1-p2), (short)0, apdubuf, (short)(ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA+p1+p2));
        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_SUB_MOD_5);
        num1.mod_sub(num2, mod);
        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_SUB_MOD_6);
        short len = num1.copy_to_buffer(apdubuf, (short) 0);
        apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short) 0, len);
    }           
    
    void test_BN_MUL_MOD(APDU apdu, short dataLen) {
        byte[] apdubuf = apdu.getBuffer();
        short p1 = (short) (apdubuf[ISO7816.OFFSET_P1] & 0x00FF);
        short p2 = (short) (apdubuf[ISO7816.OFFSET_P2] & 0x00FF);

        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_MUL_MOD_1);    
        Bignat num1 = m_testBN1;
        num1.set_size(p1);
        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_MUL_MOD_2);
        Bignat num2 = m_testBN2;
        num2.set_size(p2);
        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_MUL_MOD_3);
        Bignat mod = m_testBN3;
        mod.set_size((short) (dataLen - p1 - p2));
        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_MUL_MOD_4);
        num1.from_byte_array(p1, (short)0, apdubuf, ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA);
        num2.from_byte_array(p2, (short)0, apdubuf, (short)(ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA+p1));
        mod.from_byte_array((short)(dataLen-p1-p2), (short)0, apdubuf, (short)(ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA+p1+p2));
        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_MUL_MOD_5);
        num1.mod_mult(num1, num2, mod);
        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_MUL_MOD_6);
        short len = num1.copy_to_buffer(apdubuf, (short) 0);
        apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short) 0, len);
    }
    
    void test_BN_EXP_MOD(APDU apdu, short dataLen) {
        byte[] apdubuf = apdu.getBuffer();
        short p1 = (short) (apdubuf[ISO7816.OFFSET_P1] & 0x00FF);
        short p2 = (short) (apdubuf[ISO7816.OFFSET_P2] & 0x00FF);

        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_EXP_MOD_1);    
        Bignat num1 = m_testBN1;
        num1.set_size(p1);
        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_EXP_MOD_2);
        Bignat num2 = m_testBN2;
        num2.set_size(p2);
        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_EXP_MOD_3);
        Bignat mod = m_testBN3;
        mod.set_size((short) (dataLen - p1 - p2));
        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_EXP_MOD_4);
        num1.from_byte_array(p1, (short)0, apdubuf, ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA);
        num2.from_byte_array(p2, (short)0, apdubuf, (short)(ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA+p1));
        mod.from_byte_array((short)(dataLen-p1-p2), (short)0, apdubuf, (short)(ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA+p1+p2));
        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_EXP_MOD_5);
        num1.mod_exp(num2, mod);
        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_EXP_MOD_6);
        short len = num1.copy_to_buffer(apdubuf, (short) 0);
        apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short) 0, len);
    }
    
    void test_BN_POW2_MOD(APDU apdu, short dataLen) {
        byte[] apdubuf = apdu.getBuffer();
        short p1 = (short) (apdubuf[ISO7816.OFFSET_P1] & 0x00FF);
        short p2 = (short) (apdubuf[ISO7816.OFFSET_P2] & 0x00FF);

        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_POW2_MOD_1);
        Bignat num1 = m_testBN1;
        num1.set_size(p1);
        Bignat mod = m_testBN3;
        mod.set_size((short) (dataLen - p1));
        num1.from_byte_array(p1, (short) 0, apdubuf, ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA);
        mod.from_byte_array((short) (dataLen - p1), (short) 0, apdubuf, (short) (ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA + p1));
        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_POW2_MOD_2);
        //num1.pow2Mod_RSATrick(mod);
        num1.mod_exp2(mod);
        PM.check(PM.TRAP_BN_POW2_MOD_3);
        short len = num1.copy_to_buffer(apdubuf, (short) 0);
        apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short) 0, len);
    }
}
```

and these are sample APDUs I used for my test:

```
INS_BN_ADD:
>> B0 21 02 00 04 01 11 02 11
>> 00 03 22 90 00

INS_BN_SUB:
<< B0 22 02 00 04 43 21 11 11
>> 00 32 10 90 00

INS_BN_MUL:
<< B0 23 02 00 04 00 20 00 02
>> 00 00 00 40 90 00

INS_BN_EXP:
<< B0 24 01 00 02 02 05
>> 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 20 90 00

INS_BN_MOD:
<< B0 25 01 00 02 05 03
>> 02 90 00

INS_BN_ADD_MOD:
<< B0 30 01 01 03 05 03 03
>> 02 90 00
<< B0 30 01 01 03 05 03 04
>> 90 00

INS_BN_SUB_MOD:
<< B0 31 01 01 03 08 03 04
>> 01 90 00

INS_BN_MUL_MOD:
<< B0 32 01 01 03 04 03 05
>> 02 90 00
<< B0 32 20 20 60 E3 9D E1 72 91 BC E3 C2 93 54 42 4B 95 9F 33 0C BC E9 CA B4 0C 3F 7C 76 FD 4F DD 8F C3 1F F5 53 9E C0 3B 35 BC 2F 44 9E CD 4E 16 72 43 20 D9 DF 17 F1 8C D5 F0 4D BE 44 1D 16 C2 34 3E F0 02 F3 16 69 C4 B9 E5 A0 3F 13 82 F6 61 BE AF 89 B1 FF 45 1D D6 5A 2A 0A AF 19 27 65 D7 80 11 D2 B3 45
>> 0B 00 0B 05 B7 B0 C6 91 86 6B 14 CD 7F C1 02 4C 39 BA 3E D2 79 99 9C F2 0C D3 B6 AE 1A 7C C6 1D 90 00

INS_BN_EXP_MOD:
<< B0 33 01 01 03 02 03 06
>> 02 90 00
<< B0 33 08 03 0E 11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 00 11 22 04 23 00
>> 02 79 00 90 00

INS_BN_POW2_MOD
<< B0 35 01 00 02 03 04
>> 01 90 00
```

I did'nt add dependencies to my answer to be brief, they can be found in the github link above.

Thank you again vlp.